# How to Make QGIS on Windows use Spatialite 3.0 instead of 2.4?

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I spent all afternoon trying to figure out why my complex triggers are working fine in Spatialite-GUI but QGIS refuses to write to the layer.  Finally remembered I ran into a similar issue a few months back.  Problem is, there's no workaround this time.

I'm using triggers to force a point to snap to the nearest line on another layer, using the midpoint if no geometry is supplied, or the nearest point if it is.
Works great in 3.0, but sadly, almost all of the geo functions I'm using (Interpolate Line, Shortest Distance, etc) are not on the list of functions in 2.4.

So... I know there's been discussion about removing the built-in Spatialite from QGIS.  That seems to imply there'd be a way to point QGIS at Spatialite installed somewhere else.  Does anyone know how to make that happen?  Running Windows 7, QGIS 1.7.4.  Sorry if it sounds stupid, but I've never compiled anything so I have pretty much no idea what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the latest dev build, soon to be 1.8, OSGeo4W build a try.  It should be running 3.0.1.

[image]

*Yes the internal Spatialite was removed but as far as I know it was never used in Windows*

***also** insert typical disclaimer about using dev builds.  It should be fine but sometimes it might be unstable*

Comment: !!  I had no idea.  Man, you're always there when I'm in a pinch.  Thanks.  That settles it.  Tomorrow is the day I figure out how to build a Windows installer.  (haven't moved up because I'm supporting a dozen PCs with QGIS and need to make sure they're all on the same version, so nightlies are a no-go) Then I'll get to roll out those editable views you built for us, too!

Comment: @BFreed - Take a look at this post from Linfiniti's blog, as I think he does exactly what you are thinking of:  [Build the latest QGIS nightly build as a standalone installer for Windows](http://linfiniti.com/2012/05/quick-tip-build-the-latest-qgis-nightly-build-as-a-standalone-installer-for-windows/)

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I've been eyeing that up ever since he posted it.  I've got VirtualBox up, but so far Ubuntu failed because I can't figure out how to add any repositories (stupid Unity), and Mint Gnome and KDE both failed to run.  I've got Debian Squeeze up just now, and am trying to feel my way around.

Comment: As far as I know you shouldn't need linux to build a nightly installer. You will have to checkout the QGIS source code and install nsis but everything should be the same

Comment: drop a question on the mailing list and someone should know how to tackle it.

Comment: @BFreed - You can add the QGIS repositories by launching "Ubuntu Software Center" then choose Edit-> Software Sources menu action. Once in Software Sources, go to Other Software tab and click Add. Make sure to add the public key to your gpg keyring first before trying to install software from the QGIS repository (you will need to do this in Terminal). Another installer option is to use Synaptic package manager, available through the Software Center. http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#26-Ubuntu

Comment: @NathanW - Installed the OSGeo Nightly on one machine here.  I see Spatialite 3, but I'm getting the following debugging message: SQLite error: no such function: ST_Line_Locate_Point
That function works in Spatialite-GUI and is listed in the Functions Reference back to 3.0 beta.  Any guesses?

Comment: Very strange.  I'm getting the same.